# Computational Operator in Math

Tags: math, operator-keyword, computation

Can't seem to figure out what the "<<" operator is:

```
11<< 2 is 44
1<<1 is 2
10<<2 is 40
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute Beginner's Guide to Bit Shifting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting)

Answer (score 1):

The shift operators, bitwise shift the value on their left by the number of bits on their right:

The << shifts left and adds zeros at the right end.

The >> shifts right and adds either 0s, if value is an unsigned type, or extends the top bit (to preserve the sign) if its a signed type.

Thus,2 << 4 is 32 and -8 >> 3 is -1.

Reference:
http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/shift.html

Answer (score 0):

***This is known as Bit Shifting in computing.***

11 => 1011
So if you left shift as 11<<2, that means you are adding 2 zero bits at the end of this binary number.
1101100 (Binary) = 44

**Example Explain**

If you apply << for 1011, 2 zero bits are appended at the end of that binary value. Then the value would be
1011**00**

So If you check the decimal value of 101100,
1*(32) + 0*(16) + 1*(8) + 1*(4) + 0*(2) + 0*(1) = 44

**Short method**

- 11<<2 = 11* 2(power of 2) = 44
- 1<<1 = 1* 2(power of 1) = 2
- 10<<2 = 10* 2(power of 2) = 40
- a << n = a*2(power of n)